# What nutrients are necessary for Bacillus subtilis germination?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, lab-techniques, amino-acids, germination

What are the necessary conditions to germinate *Bacillus subtilis* spores? Under laboratory conditions, spores of *B. subtilis* are often heat-activated for 30 min at 70°C to increase their germination responses to nutrients. Most papers use either L-valine or L-alanine amino acids to germinate.

However, I would like to know if those are necessary nutrients for germination.

**Are there other nutrients that can germinate *B. subtilis*?**

Comment: Your own efforts to answer this question? Again.

Comment: To get you started in answering your question, here's a good paper: [Analysis of the germination of spores of Bacillus subtilis with temperature sensitive spo mutations in the spoVA operon](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.femsle.2004.08.022). I would recommend reading section 3.3 - **Germination of spoVA mutant spores**.